# Force JTextArea not to fit the JPanel

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am making my first program **in Java**, which would be a simple text editor..
Well, I have a JPanel and I want to add a JTextArea in it..But the JTextArea fits all the JPanel,so I cant add anything else like a Button in my JPanel..
I have tried to resize my JTextArea but nothing happens..

The code I have used:

```
TextArea text = new TextArea();
text.setSize(300, 200);
JFrame.add(text);
```

Comment: You should read up on layout managers in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html Using a layout manager removes the need for setSize(). The layout manager does the job. In your case you will probably have several JPanels inside a JPanel etc. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mattiash !

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

final JTextArea area = new JTextArea(2,20);
frame.getContentPane().add(area);

JButton button1 = new JButton("press me");
JButton button2 = new JButton("press me");


frame.getContentPane().add(button1);
frame.getContentPane().add(button2);

frame.setSize(300,300);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```